# Pressure Sensor and Arduino

Tags: arduino-mega

I am currently working on reading pressure values using a tekscan a201 sensor. The sensors I have are limited to 25lbs.

My plan is to use eight on these sensors of them with a arduino Mega. Since I am measuring the resistance, I am thinking of making a 8 similar voltage divider circuits and grabbing the voltage reading via arduinos analog pins.

At the moment, I am not sure how to convert these readings to engineering units. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have not previously met the Flexscan sensors but from the datasheet it appears that there are versions of the A201 rated at 100 pounds are you committed to the 25 lbf version?

[**A201 datasheet here**](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEkQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tekscan.com%2Fpdf%2FFLX-A201-force-sensor.pdf&ei=cszJVOrPJZLN8gWU_4Bw&usg=AFQjCNGNy5nCyCNgagOzaIMfsUIpSFlRGg&sig2=_D791hWWRz5tzqHSp0zcxg&bvm=bv.84607526,d.dGY&cad=rja)

Here is a [**15 page user manual**](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CFUQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tekscan.com%2Fpdf%2FFLX-FlexiForce-Sensors-Manual.pdf&ei=cszJVOrPJZLN8gWU_4Bw&usg=AFQjCNGCYZTma0vkXT0e2BsH7Y07yQ_tcw&sig2=ZMxG630bjh44caLTmokRJg&bvm=bv.84607526,d.dGY&cad=rja) thatexplains how to produce a voltage output using a single opamp per sensor - bottom of page 9.

[Many idea starters **here**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=tekscan+a201&biw=1745&bih=977&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=cszJVOrPJZLN8gWU_4Bw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ)

---

What is your application and why do you wish to use these sensors. These seem to be a low accuracy alternative to eg load cells and seem to be expensive for what you get. If you need 8 for your task a loadcell based solution may e cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for responding. 
I am helping out a few friends who are planning to use these sensors to test out compression wear for women. They already brought the tekscan sensors so I am kind of stuck with them.

Comment: You are right, they don't seem to be very accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I decided go with the voltage divider approach as it seemed simple enough. The sensors themselves needed to be calibrated, which took me a while as I didn't have the required weights.

After the calibration, I used the line of best fit approach to find an equation that translated voltage to force.